# How to remove help tabs?

Tags: contextual-help

Is there any way to remove the help tabs? 
I'm looking to remove these tabs not to hide them with CSS.

On the `wp-admin/includes/screen.php` there are a couple of lines that mention this but no idea how to create something to remove the help tab.

Is there any way to create something similar to: `add_filter('screen_options_show_screen', '__return_false');` but to remove the Help tab ?

From the `screen.php` file:

```
 647      /**
 648       * Removes a help tab from the contextual help for the screen.
 649       *
 650       * @since 3.3.0
 651       *
 652       * @param string $id The help tab ID.
 653       */
 654    public function remove_help_tab( $id ) {
 655          unset( $this->_help_tabs[ $id ] );
 656      }
 657  
 658      /**
 659       * Removes all help tabs from the contextual help for the screen.
 660       *
 661       * @since 3.3.0
 662       */
 663    public function remove_help_tabs() {
 664          $this->_help_tabs = array();
 665      }
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You need to use the [`contextual_help`](http://adambrown.info/p/wp_hooks/hook/contextual_help?version=3.3&file=wp-admin/includes/screen.php) help filter.

```
add_filter( 'contextual_help', 'wpse50723_remove_help', 999, 3 );
function wpse50723_remove_help($old_help, $screen_id, $screen){
    $screen->remove_help_tabs();
    return $old_help;
}
```

The filter is for the old context help (pre 3.3). (*I'm not sure it matters what is returned...?*).

In any case the filter should be called late (hence 999) because plug-ins could add their own help tabs to pages. This is partly why `admin_head` is not an ideal hook.

Comment: As stated [here](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/contextual_help/) the `contextual_help` has since been depreciated.

Answer (score 9):

Add this you your `functions.php` file:

```
add_action('admin_head', 'mytheme_remove_help_tabs');
function mytheme_remove_help_tabs() {
    $screen = get_current_screen();
    $screen->remove_help_tabs();
}
```

This will remove tabs ant the 'Help' button from all admin pages.